# Javascript googlemap api document.write() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
<script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();      

    <%for (String st : t.keySet()) {%>  
        printGeocode(   <%=t.get(st)[1]%>       ,   <%=t.get(st)[0]%>       );      
    <%}%>
        function printGeocode(x, y) {
            document.write("Test Check1<br>"); // work fine
            alert("test Check1"); // work fine
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng' : latlng
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {                       
                        document.write(results[1].formatted_address+"<br>"); // didn't work
                        alert(results[1].formatted_address); // Work Fine
                    } else {
                        alert('No results found');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

this is my source

alert(String) is work fine

but document.write is doesn't work

what is different between first " `document.write("Test Check1<br>"); // work fine`"

and  `document.write(results[1].formatted_address+"<br>");`

```
i can't understand `alert(results[1].formatted_address); // Work Fine`
```

appear alert address why

```
document.write(results[1].formatted_address+"<br>"); // didn't work
```

didn't appear on webpage?

Comment: Using document.write is not good.  Better manipulate the DOM something like `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address+"<br>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.write()` API is only safe to use while the DOM is being built by the browser. Using it in a callback from the maps API means that by the time it runs, the DOM has been finalized. At that point, a call to `document.write()` means implicitly that the DOM should be wiped out and a new one prepared.

If you need to add content, use the DOM manipulation APIs and/or `innerHTML`.